# d3js: ordinal scale with not unique labels

Tags: d3.js

I try to create a heat-map with text. Using the examples I created the following code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < trgLength; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < srcLength; ++j) {
            var newItem = {}
            newItem.srcWord = decodeHTML(data[k].src[j])
            newItem.trgWord = decodeHTML(data[k].trg[i])
            newItem.value = data[k].attentions[i][j]
            sen_data.push(newItem)
        }
    }
    var x_elements = data[k].src.map(function(item){return decodeHTML(item)}),
        y_elements = data[k].trg.map(function(item){return decodeHTML(item)});

    var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(x_elements)
        .rangeBands([0, x_elements.length * itemSize]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .tickFormat(function (d) {
            return d;
        })
        .orient("top")

    var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(y_elements)
        .rangeBands([0, y_elements.length * itemSize]);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .tickFormat(function (d) {
            return d;
        })
        .orient("left");
     var cells = svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(sen_data)
        .enter().append('g').append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'cell')
        .attr('width', cellSize)
        .attr('height', cellSize)
        .attr('y', function (d) {
            return yScale(d.trgWord);
        })
        .attr('x', function (d) {
            return xScale(d.srcWord);
        })
```

This works just fine if the words in the sentences (src and target) are unique. If not then only one instance of the word is plotted. 
Is there a way to encode words uniquely? I was thinking about using the position in the sentence and then changing the labels but I could not find an easy way to accomplish that

Comment: The dupe target explains how to use the indices. Also, your usage of `range` in an ordinal scale is not correct.

Comment: thank you! I did not see that answer. However, I don't see in the answers given there how to change the labels. I tried it using the indices as the domain but then I'm left with them as labels on the axis or did I miss something?

Comment: Use those indices in the data array.